# Testing Angular and Express with Karma

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm making (my first ever) webapp using MEAN (mongo, express, angular, node) and I'm having trouble figuring how to correctly test both the backend and the frontend. I've configured Karma and Jasmine to run my "angular tests" but I'm not quite sure how to run any tests I'd write with Jasmine for the express/node code.

My understanding - which is probably flawed - is that Karma is meant specifically for testing front end frameworks because it kicks up browser. If that's true, what test runner can/should I use to test the backend (ideally, I'd like to use the same test runner for both the frontend and backend). If my understanding is flawed, how can I configure Karma for both sets of test suites?

Here's what my karma.conf.js looks like right now:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Feb 10 2015 14:37:31 GMT-0600 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'public/javascripts/*.js',
      'ng_tests/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: I haven't done much testing with karma, i tend to do all of my testing with mocha. You don't need to launch a browser to run tests on controllers and services if you test them individually and mock all dependencies.

Comment: You will need two different test frameworks for front and back end. Since karma injects the tests into the browser, it cannot run the node tests.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. Any chance you can recommend something for me to check out?